# Does QGIS Server support QGIS project with Oracle layers?

Tags: oracle-spatial, qgis-server

QGIS recently got native Oracle support. I was wondering if QGIS Server supports generating WMS and WFS from a QGIS project with Oracle Spatial layers. I just tested this but I did not succeed...

Comment: Expecting it will at QGIS 2.0 Server stable release. There are many QGIS developers (wizards) on GIS-SE that might know more than that.